# How to call a dialog box from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm currently using PrimeFaces to create a web service and ran into a snag while trying to show() a dialog box using a javascript function instead of an onclick="__.show();" command.

What I would like to do is:

```
function displayPopup(){

statusDialog.show();

}
```

and if I do something like

```
a href=”#” onclick=”statusDialog.show()”
```

Then it works just fine (but not the work flow I require).

This is the PrimeFaces code:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Your request is in progress..." draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <img alt="Banner Right" src="#/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" border="0"/>
</p:dialog>
```

This is the generated code:

```
jQuery(function() {statusDialog = new PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog('j_idt41',{autoOpen:false,minHeight:0,draggable: false,modal: true,resizable:false,closable:false});});
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? If so, please share.

Comment: in IE or Firefox nothing happens.  no errors or anything, very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen show() before, but you can generate an alert with the alert() function, or an alert with "Yes" and "No" buttons using the confirm() function, `int confirm(String text)`.

It sounds like you just want to call alert("Your request is in progress...").
I don't think you can show images in the basic alert, but 5 seconds on google gave me this site:

http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/custom-alert-box.html

Which seems to solve your problem.

Comment: Well yes, alert would do "sort of" what my want but it's not what I need because alerts are pretty ugly (my apologies).

Comment: @vedar123 Did you try the custom alert box I linked to? That should be able to do what you want by replacing the alert with your own design.

Comment: Still trying to browse around to use the PrimeFaces method but I'll give your method a shot tonight.  :)